# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using datetimepicker and I have problem : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function.
I cannot fix it. Help me...

My lib

```
 <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/datapicker/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/datapicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/dataTables/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

And code :

```
   <div>
                    Tadbirkorlik sifatida ro'yhatdan otkazish inspeksiyasida royhatdan otgan sana
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" style="width: 1005px"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're including 2 versions of jQuery and the datetimepicker library you can remove one of each, preferably the non 'min.js' versions.

Comment: moment.js is one of its dependencies, doesn't look as though you are including that

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see bootstrap's javascript included, try adding it and see if it works then. Also you have to choose between .min.js or .js files, you should not include them. There is no point doing such thing.

Hope that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please replace your following code

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

with this and try again

```
$('#datetimepicker1 input').datetimepicker();
```

also please remove one of this line

```
<script src="../js/datapicker/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/datapicker/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you are loading jquery twice.